# Display custom property values when sharing with facebook

Tags: facebook-opengraph, share-open-graph

I have the following metatags set

```
og:title        Supercompany
og:url          https://xxxxx/Business/Grumble/?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
og:image        https://xxxxxxx/Content/Images/logo4fb.png?23122014
og:type         xxxxxx:organization
og:hashtags     #xxx #xrfgg #sdsv #vdsdg #vdvdvd
og:description  aaaa | cghydgdegezhztt
```

When I share the above, only the description shows up. How do I get the hashtags to show?

I am using the below to share to FB.

```
FB.ui({
        method: 'share',
        href: linkToShare,
        action_type: 'xxxxxx:yyy',
        action_properties: JSON.stringify({
            organization: linkToShare
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't solve this with share, so I ended up concatenating the hashtags with the description and sharing with feed instead of share.

```
FB.ui({
       method: 'feed',
       link: linkToShare,
       description: hashtags
    }

hashtags = description + " " + hashtags
```